# Авторизация Socialite в Laravel через аккаунт Vk

Tags: laravel

Установил laravel/socialite и socialiteproviders/vkontakte

При вызове первого маршрута api/vk/auth выдает ошибку: "There is no services entry for vkontakte".

В строке 122 в vendor/socialiteproviders/manager/src/Helpers/ConfigRetriever.php, вот это место

```
if (empty($configArray)) {
    // If we are running in console we should spoof values to make Socialite happy...
    if (app()->runningInConsole()) {
        $configArray = [
            'client_id' => "{$this->providerIdentifier}_KEY",
            'client_secret' => "{$this->providerIdentifier}_SECRET",
            'redirect' => "{$this->providerIdentifier}_REDIRECT_URI",
        ];
    } else {
        throw new MissingConfigException("There is no services entry for $providerName");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в файл config/services.php

```
'vkontakte' => [    
  'client_id' => env('VKONTAKTE_CLIENT_ID'),  
  'client_secret' => env('VKONTAKTE_CLIENT_SECRET'),  
  'redirect' => env('VKONTAKTE_REDIRECT_URI') 
],
```

Измените свойство `listen` чтобы слушать события `SocialiteWasCalled`.

И добавьте событие в ваш массив listen[] в файле app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.

```
protected $listen = [
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        // ... Другие провайдеры
        \SocialiteProviders\VKontakte\VKontakteExtendSocialite::class.'@handle',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть перевели текст...